# What's the difference between if(!$variable) and if(isset($variable))?

Tags: php

What is the difference between `if(!$variable)` and `if(isset($variable))`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, the answer is pretty simple. `isset($var)` returns whether or not a variable exists and is not null, where `!$var` tells you if that variable is `true`, or anything that evaluates to `true` (such as a non-empty string).  This is summarized in the first table of [this documentation page](https://secure.php.net/manual/types.comparisons.php).

Also, using `!$var` will output a notice that you're using an undefined variable, whereas `isset($var)` won't do that.

Mind you, they are two different things:

```
<?php
var_dump( isset($foo) ); // false.
var_dump( !$foo );       // true, but with a warning.

$foo = false;
var_dump( isset($foo) ); // true
var_dump( !$foo );       // true.
```

Comment: the document page really helpful. see document page for the best answer https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 3):

If a variable is not set, then you will get a warning when using if(!Variable).

Comment: And this kind of warning should be encouraged ... "declare" your damn variables.

Answer (score 0):

They are two different statements

1. in the first you check if a variable is false hence the '!'
2. here you check if a variable is actually set to some value other then null.