# Difference between if(isset($var)) and if($var)

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Whats the difference between if(!Variable) and if(isset($variable)) ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164972/whats-the-difference-between-ifvariable-and-ifissetvariable)

In Facebooks php API example they use if($var){ //do something }else{ //do something else}
whick got me thinking about the difference of if($var) and if(isset($var)). The first sure looks neater but can I surely use it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using

```
if ($var)
```

You'll test if `$var` contains a value that's not false -- 1 is true, 123 is too, ...

For more informations about what is considered as true or false, you should take a look at [**Converting to Boolean**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting).

Using [**`isset()`**](http://www.php.net/isset), you'll test if a variable has been set -- i.e. if any not-null value has been written to it.

Answer (score 9):

The difference is that the `isset` will be true for any variable that has been declared/initalized to anything (besides null).  the `if($var)` is true for all values of var OTHER THAN those that evaluate to false (0, '', null, false, etc).

So the difference is for values that are not null, but still evaluate to false: 0, '' (empty string), false, empty array, etc.

Try this:

```
$var = '';  //or equivalently 0, false, ''

if(isset($var)) echo 'a';
if($var) echo 'b';
```

Answer (score 3):

isset will check if a variable has been set, and if ($var) will check if the variable is true.

if ($var) will throw a warning if the variable isn't set, so it's best practice to do this

```
if (isset($var) && $var)
```

Which will check if it's set AND it's true

Answer (score 2):

The key difference here is between *variables* and *values*.  The two items of code you refer to different concepts.

```
if (isset($var)) {
```

This tests to see if a variable has been set.  The only other check it does is to see that `$var` is not set to `null` (since that is pretty much equivalent to unsetting it).

```
if ($var) {
```

This tests to see if the value that `$var` refers to is truthy.  This may seem like an odd concept, but sometimes non-intuitive things happen in PHP with comparisions.  The conditional will pass if the value of `$var` is anything that is `true` when converted to a boolean.  See [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) for a list of what is converted to `true` and what is converted to `false`.

### Finally

There is often a case for using both.  Because `isset` is a language feature not a standard function, you can pass any variable name to it and it won't throw an error.  It will merely return `false` if the variable is not defined. However, if you try using a non-initialised variable outside that context, you'll get errors reported.

That's why you'll often see code that checks to see that the value is *both* set *and* truthy:

```
if (isset($var) && $var) {
```

Answer (score 1):

if($var) tests the truth value of $var, while isset($var) checks if $var has been initialized or not. If $var has not been initialized, if($var) will throw a notice "unknown variable var". But isset will check if $var is set; if $var is initialized it will return its value otherwise return false.