# How to load php vars from an external file with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, variables

I had this code inside the `<div id="chtmsg">` on a page that shows a messenger...

**PHP :**

```
if($perguntas){
  for($c=0;$c<count($perguntas);$c++){
    $perguntas[$c]->tipo == 'F' ? $class = 'message_F' : $class = 'message_P';
    $hora = substr($perguntas[$c]->hora, 0, 5);
    echo "<li class=\"".$class."\"><p>".$perguntas[$c]->mensagem."</p><span>".$pergunta->databr($perguntas[$c]->data)." - ".$hora."</span></li>";
    if($perguntas[$c]->tipo=='F' and $perguntas[$c]->status == 0){
      $pergunta->marcaRespLida($perguntas[$c]->id);
    }
  }
}
```

It works very well. So, I wanted to load it with js to refresh all new messages only inside the div #chtmsg and then I created a file msg.php and with the `<?php include("msg");?>` it continues working good, but with js I needed to put the path...

**HTML :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get(hostGlobal+'site/modulos/produto/msg.php', function (result) {
            $('#chtmsg').html(result);
            scTop();
        });
    }, 3000);
});
```

But its shows the error inside de div...

> Notice: Undefined variable: perguntas in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sisconbr-sistema-novo/site/modulos/produto/msg.php on line 3

I tested other codes inside the msg.php file and works ok without variables...

Comment: Where you define `$perguntas` variable? can you define it inside the `msg.php`?

Comment: In fact, your variable is not defined. If you call the php file in your browser, you will see the same message. You need to send the variable as parameter in the $.get query.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought...

Your first line in PHP

```
if($perguntas){
```

Should perhaps check if defined like so

```
if(isset($perguntas)){
```

My suggestion explained in another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5689445/5578802)

Answer (score 0):

For better code, You should preferably use:

```
if (isset($perguntas) && is_array($perguntas)){
```