# Admin restrinction fails from an irrelevant function

Tags: php, session, csrf

I have this piece of code in PHP web app.

```
  if (isset($require_admin) && $require_admin) {
    if(!check_admin()) {
        $toolContent_ErrorExists = $langCheckAdmin;
        $errorMessagePath = "../../";
    }
  }
```

The normal behavior is that if the variable $require_admin is set and true,the code will check if the visit is by the admin.

I try to add a similar piece of code some lines below so as to make other things like checking for cross-origin(especially CSRF) requests.

```
if (isset($require_token) && $require_token) {
    if( !checkToken( $mycsrf_token, $myform)) {
        $toolContent_ErrorExists = $langCheckToken;
        $errorMessagePath = "../../";
    }
}
```

I had in mind that in this way i will have a check that the posted forms I get are valid and if no,there would be an error message.
However,when $require_token is set and true,and the condition is verified i have a very strange result.Not only nothing happens for the csrf validation,but the above function stops working properly and admin restriction stops to work.

I know the question maybe is ambiguous but I cannot get what's going on there.I'm not so experienced on web programming and totally new in PHP so maybe someone could have a better idea!

Comment: what error do you get - and doing `&& $var` doesn't mean `&& true` it just mean that variable is set - not that it's true

Comment: I should get an error but I don't anymore.A guest can view a page which is exclusively accessed by the admin.About $var are you sure? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689430/difference-between-ifissetvar-and-ifvar

Comment: add some error handling - make sure you have display_errors and display_startup_errors set to 1 in your .ini :) and yeah it's saying it's not false, so the expression result to true because it's not false if that makes sense? Though my comment is confusing to be fair, by is set I mean there's a value against it - that includes empty strings `''` will return true using `if ($var)`