# PHP Ternary Operator checking if variable contains something?

Tags: php

Consider the following (simplified to the bare bones):

```
abstract class Validator {    

    public function __construct($data = null)
    {
        $this->data = $data ?: Input::all();
    }
}


$validation = new PageValidator($data);
```

'Input::all' is returning an array. $data is also an array.

The bit I am struggling with is:

```
$this->data = $data ?: Input::all();
```

I think it is essentially doing this:

```
    if(!$data) {
        $this->data = Input::all();
    } else {
        $this->data = $data;
    };
```

But I don't really understand how?

Comment: Yes, that's what it does if you're using PHP 5.3 or above.  If you're using PHP < 5.3, you have to write it `$this->data = $data ? $data : Input::all();`.

Answer (score 6):

It's a [feature of PHP 5.3](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.new-features.php) and above:

> The ternary operator now has a shorthand form: `?:`.

Comment: Genius ;) so does calling if($data) return false if $data=null ? No need to use isset() / empty()?

Comment: it'll return false, but it will also issue an undefined variable warning if $data wasn't previously used. that's why isset() is used - it bypasses the warning and acts as a "does this variable actually exist" test.

Comment: @dopey As @Mark B said, if `$data` is null it will return false but with a warning. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5164993/2612112) for more information.

Comment: @dopey In this case it would never issue a warning because it's being defined in the method declaration. If it's not provided by whatever is calling the constructor, it will be set to `null`, which is different than undefined, but both will return false with `isset`.

Answer (score 5):

Your understanding of the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) is correct.

The exact syntax you've shown that omits the middle part of the operator was a feature added in PHP 5.3:

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

The full expression, without omission, is:

```
$this->data = $data ? $data : Input::all();
```

Which translates to what you've assumed:

```
if($data) {
    $this->data = $data;
} else {
    $this->data = Input::all();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`?:` is an abbreviation for a ternary operator since PHP 5.3

So, `?:` is like `||` is for `javascript` in the following case:

`var myVar = var1 || var2`

If the `var1` is evaluated to true, `myVar` will be this one, otherwise `var2`.

**Notes:**

`0`, `''`, `false` and `null` are evaluated to false, so if you have the following:

```
$data = 0;
$this->data = $data ?: 'someVal';
echo $this->data;
```

You'll get `"someVal"` as result.

For that cases use `isset` or `empty`.

Answer (score 0):

try this form:

```
$this->data = $data ? $data : Input::all();
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer anything

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP's question, or help to "understand" why it's the case.